# Halting and continuing embebbed ruby code

Tags: ruby, scripting, embedded-ruby, pausing-execution

I call Ruby functions from my C++ code through the embedding commands (rb_eval and the like). Is there any way to stop the execution of the code partway, save the local variables, and restart it from the same spot later?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store Ruby variables for use later, you want to use a feature called [Marshaling](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ospace.html#S6).  Create a class in which you can store all variables you wish to save, and use `Marshal::dump` to store the class into a file.  The data can be reconstituted into a Ruby variable again later by using `Marshal::load`.

Restarting your code from a particular point might not be as easy.  You can marshal classes and data but not necessarily the state of the entire Ruby interpreter itself.  One possibility is to store enough state information in your marshaled data to let you re-load the data and figure out where you need to pick up.